# Arch Linux pacman specifying package version

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, version

I know that I can define wanted package version in `pacman` like shown in its manual `pacman -S "bash>=3.2"`. But how do I know what versions are available?

I also know that `pacman` is creating copy of mirrors upon syncing in .db files in `/var/lib/pacman/sync/`, but those files are not human-readable.

And what if I want to install some version `virtualbox` for example, that I hope is in mirrors somewhere, that wouldn't require newer version of `linux` (set as `IgnorePkg` in `pacman.conf`) than I have installed (because of `nvidia` drivers)? How do I know what version that is and if it is available?

Comment: "But how do I know what versions are available?" isn't `pacman -Si package_name` enough?

Comment: @Braiam No, that gives you only the newest available.

Comment: In the meantime I downloaded wanted packages manually from Arch Rollback Machine at http://seblu.net/a/arm/ But this approach is requiring manually downloading and trying to install wanted packages which is really time-consuming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't specify a version that easily, as a rolling release, `pacman` will only provide the latest. When you install something, that package is stored in your computer on the `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/` dir, so if you want to downgrade one version or specify another, you have to use `pacman -U` and the name of the package on your cache. There are "time machine" repos out there where people just stores old packages, you can download the version you want and use `pacman -U` to install it.

Be aware that you have to "ignore" the updates of that package if you don't want it to update, to see how, check the wiki in the pacman page or [this Arch-Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages#Q:_I_cannot_downgrade_a_package.2C_because_of_dependencies).

In your case, add

```
IgnorePkg=bash
```

to `/etc/pacman.conf`.

Comment: I know of pacman -U and previously installed packages and also of Arch Rollback Machines. My question was really meant on how to ease the process of searching the right package version.

Comment: @meridius You are asking the wrong question: Arch is a rolling release, the only version of a package--for all intents--is the current version. [Partial upgrades are unsupported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported).

Comment: "as a rolling release, pacman will only provide the latest." Wrong!

Rolling realease does not imply that. You can have a rolling release which supports older packages.

Comment: @meridius I used the `pacman -U` option with the full url of the package i needed, at https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/. Also you may want to add that special package to the ignore list, otherwise it will be overrided. @jasonwryan, Rolling release has many benefits, but somethins ship happes and you're forced to keep some "not that new" version :D untill fixes are applied.