# How to install packages with Pacman from a list contained in a text file?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, manjaro, pacman

I installed a minimal version of Manjaro Cinnamon edition, and now want to upgrade it to the full edition. The list of packages are available in this [text file](https://osdn.net/projects/manjaro-community/storage/cinnamon/20.0.1/manjaro-cinnamon-20.0.1-200511-linux56-pkgs.txt).

How to install them with Pacman without painfully typing the name of the hundreds of packages?
I am attaching the first 5 lines of the file, for convenience.

```
a52dec 0.7.4-10
aalib 1.4rc5-13
accountsservice 0.6.55-2
acl 2.2.53-3
acpi 1.7-3
```

Comment: You probably only need to show the first 5 lines or so... that’s a lot of scrolling.

Comment: What is the command used to generate that list?

Comment: Reason I'm asking is that `apparmor` would be installed according to the list. I have KDE Plasma on Arch Linux (in a VM) without `apparmor`.

Comment: @DKBose I don't know how the list was generated. I got the list from https://osdn.net/projects/manjaro-community/storage/cinnamon/20.0.1/manjaro-cinnamon-20.0.1-200511-linux56-pkgs.txt/

Comment: Hmmm. That's an interesting list. They've got `flatpak` and `kvantum` and `snapd` as well.

Comment: @DKBose  Nowadays Kvantum is required to properly theme Qt apps in gtk based DEs because the default gtk theme in qt5ct has a major bug. (You answered this in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233429/qt-apps-are-very-slow-to-load-in-xubuntu-20-04-when-export-qt-qpa-platformtheme) . However I don't see why flatpak and snaps are there in the default packages, as Manjaro is already a rolling release.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about kvantum. I don't know how different Manjaro is from Arch, but on Arch, `pacman -Ss cinnamon` gives you a list to pick from. I guess if you install enough of those, you'll have a complete cinnamon.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks, I'll see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'cat input_file | cut "-d " -f1 |  xargs pacman -S'
```

or a simpler version:

```
$ awk '{print $1}'  input_file |  xargs pacman -S
```

or

```
$ sudo pacman -S $(awk '{print $1}'  input_file)
```

Where `input_file` contains all your packages to be installed, one to a line.

**Word of caution**:
As you undoubtedly know, Archlinux is a rolling release package, so specifying version to be installed is [not recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103868/72707) and means you could actually break dependencies and, ultimately, your system overall.
For that reason alone I cut away the version info in your package records in `input_file`...

If you insists on a rolled back (i.e. "old") version of some package, you can roll back on Arch Linux, but I recommend you do that by hand, not in an automated way, only if you know exactly what you are getting into.

HTH.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not on linux right now so I can't test it, but this should work...

```
pacman -S $(cat yourfilename | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

If that doesn't work, then this should

```
pacman -S $(echo $(cat yourfilename | cut -d' ' -f1))
```

The goal here is to give pacman the output of the file as one line, without the version numbering, and each line separated by a space.

Comment: What would the `cut -d` do? Will it remove the version numbers?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi yes, it has to, as far as I'm aware pacman does not accept version numbering as an argument, at least not such a simple one; and your question didn't ask for fetching the specific versions of the programs either. Edit: See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103859/arch-linux-pacman-specifying-package-version in case you're wondering, it should not matter for your purposes.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi yes it removes the version numbers.